# Appending values to Cassandra Map column from Spark Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra

I have cassandra table with 3 columns.

```
id text,
value text,
mappings map<text,text>
```

Lets say sample data is as follows:

```
id        | value       | mappings
-----------------------------------------------
1ABC      | xyz         | {"a":"abc","b":"bcd"}
```

In a spark job I have computed a new value for id `1ABC`'s `b` mapping as a HashMap `Ex: "b":"xyz"`(can convert map to JavaRDD)

How can I append (overwrite) this value into the table using cassandra java spark connector? I was looking at [this](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md#modifying-cql-collections) example on how to handle CQL collections appending but I can't seem to figure out how to do this in Java.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50598458/spark-cassandra-connector-java-api-append-remove-data-in-a-collection-fail

Comment: @undefined_variable this link isn't something that is related - he is asking about appending to map, and example is just saving the data into cassandra from Spark Java job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this as below.

Create a cassandra connector either by passing new params or using the same from the Spark session.

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;

CassandraConnector connector = CassandraConnector.apply(spark.sparkContext().conf()); // or pass different values for spark.cassandra.connection.host, username and password

rdd.foreach(new VoidFunction<TestBean>() {
        @Override
        public void call(TestBean t) throws Exception {
            final String id = t.getId();
            final Map<String, String> mappings = t.getMappings();
            boolean isUpdated = connector.withSessionDo(new AbstractFunction1<Session, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean apply(Session v1) {
                    ResultSet updateResultSet = v1.execute(v1.prepare("update test set mappings = mappings + ? where id = ?")
                            .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM)
                            .bind(mappings, id));
                    return updateResultSet.wasApplied();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: How to do this in Scala?